# pip-18.0 has 'logging module not found' error

Tags: python, logging, pip

Having just upgraded to  pip-18.0
all uses of pip produce this error:

```
...\site-packages\pip\_internal\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    import logging
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'logging'

logging.py exists in \site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\
(and also contains an 'import logging' statement!)
```

I suppose I could move it up a directory level or update _init to 'import utils.logging'
In fact lots of my programs' packages eg numpy are now failing with no logging module.   I have now identified the problem:

> > > import logging

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
    import logging
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'logging'

> > > import lib2to3.logging

lib2to3 is a subdir of Lib, containing the logging module,
but is no longer found in the module search.

Comment: Please don't! I doubt `import logging` is intended to import `\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\logging.py`, I'm sure it's rather intended to import [logging package from Python stdlib](https://docs.python.org/library/logging.html). Verify that you have `\logging` package sibling to `\site-packages`.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, running OpenWrt/LEDE 17.01.4 on the client, I had installed most of Python3 via:

```
opkg install python3-light
```

when I received the `ImportError: No module named logging`. I needed to separately install the `logging` package:

```
opkg install python3-logging
```

The above is enough to run the Ansible `ping` module. To run the `setup` module you also need:

```
opkg install python3-multiprocessing python3-distutils
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by moving logging up from Lib/lib2to3/  to  Lib/
where import canm now find it.

Answer (score 0):

I would add to @bitinerant 's answer that also the following package needs to be installed:

```
opkg install python-openssl python-codecs
```

for the ping and setup modules to work on python2 based systems